# java swing program for JTextField

Tags: java, swing

How to change the JTEXTFIELD properties by pass the parameters without using the default functions.For Example if i want to change the JTextField LEFT property means using parameter (control name,left,100) like this.how to i do change JtextField property by passing parameter to the JTextField Property?

Comment: This question is not that clear, and if I understand properly and you want to modify the object fields directly, it is usually just wrong.

Comment: Show the code you're using now, and explain what you want to do differently, in code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to call the setter methods indirectly. You could, in theory, use it to set field values without calling setters, but don't do that, it breaks encapsulation.

Easiest way to use reflection API would be not to call it directly, but to use a ready-made library - for example, [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/):

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(textField, "left", 100);
```